# Nginx seems to only allow 1 connection per session / browser

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and am trying to serve web pages and files with it.

I noticed that when the browser is downloading a file, other tabs trying to access any page / other files will stay loading and only be processed when the file download is finished. I suspected nginx may have been limiting requests by IP but tried [limitconn](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) to no avail.

Then I opened a separate browser on the same machine and it was strangely able to access the site as usual while a file was downloading in the other one. Similarly, I could concurrently access the site with a separate machine. So I believe the issue is likely unrelated to number of worker processes, connection limits, etc., but am still unsure.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

---

My configs are quite default but I will put them below. I am using a Flask app with uWSGI

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
#worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        #limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
        #limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=serv:10m;
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/x>
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name (domain) www.(domain);

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/(user)/(domain)/(domain).sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your nginx configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have edited the question

Comment: Unless there is something really weird in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` I think the problem is in your Flask app. Did you configure it properly? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/

Comment: @AlexeyTen My `conf.d` folder seems to be empty. I tried the instructions [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/proxy_fix/) but the problem persists (to be honest, I'm not sure what exactly to do other than this). Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Please provide your full running config with `nginx -T`